# input filter regex single decimal to allow 0 or 5 only

Tags: javascript, regex

i had a input filter function look like this:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
        if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
        } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
        }
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

currently im using this regex pattern:

```
^\d*[.,]?\d{0,1}$
```

which return following:

```
a        == false
1.0      == true
3.5      == true
1.1      == true
2.34     == false
11.0     == true
1.1      == true
1.2      == true
1.3      == true
1.5      == true
1.0      == true
2        == true
```

expected result:

```
a        == false
1.0      == true
3.5      == true
1.1      == false
2.34     == false
11.0     == true
1.1      == false
1.2      == false
1.3      == false
1.5      == true
1.0      == true
2        == true
```

i tried using:

```
^\d*[.,]?\d{0,1}[05]$
```

it seem correct on regex tester site, but when apply to input filter it allow me to key in 0 and 5 only, not other number and also the dot (.)

[regextester Link here](https://regex101.com/r/M33wr5/2/)

**UPDATE 1: JSfiddle link added**

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7gs6yqah/)

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `^\d*[.,]?\d{0,1}[05]$` the first 3 parts are optional so it would match a single 0 or 5 only.

The `\d{0,1}` allows for a single digit 0-9 which can be followed by a 0 or 5.

If you want to be able to allow it to be typed, you could make the dot and the 0 or 5 at the end optional using

```
^\d+\.?[05]?$
```

Then do another validation when processing the data to verify the whole pattern matching 1+ digits with an optional part that matches a dot and a digit 0 or 5 using a character class.

```
^\d+(?:\.[05])?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[05])?` Optionally match a dot and either 0 or 5
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gELKwf/1)

Comment: it do not allow me to key in the dot (.)

Comment: Can't say this one won't work, but seems that he specifies both comma and dot to be valid separators, and what about `1.50`? Guess it's also a valid answer to his input.

Comment: @Teddybugs If you want to be able to type it you could use `^\d+\.?[05]?$` but note that will also match a digit with only a dot like `1.` See https://regex101.com/r/aZ2jmg/1 What you could do is use this pattern and do another check using the pattern from the answer when processing the data.

Comment: @NoureldeanSwearky Perhaps that is also allowed, only the title of the question states `allow 0 or 5 only` and there is no comma in the example data.

Comment: @Thefourthbird True, it shouldn't necessarily allow for `0`s after the `5`s, that's fair, but the comma is specified in his current regex even if it isn't specified in his examples.

Comment: please ignore the comma, i just want the decimal point with (dot) .

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
^\d+(?:[\.,][05]0*)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wiiky4/1)